# Rails Full calendar can not shown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, indexing, calendar

I am trying to implement [Example](http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/02/18/fancy-calendars-for-your-web-application-with-fullcalendar.html) but I am having troubles at the beginning. I can not see the calendar on the page. However, when I download the code from the web page and make arrangements it works.

So what I did is to

1. create a demo folder (rails new Demo)
2. generate scaffold (rails g scaffold Event title:string description:text start_time:datetime end_time:datetime)
3. rake db:migrate
4. Then I added the `gem 'fullcalendar-rails'`
5. bundle install
6. added the js and css
7. added js to initiate the calender
8. put div tag to `index.html.erb`

So still I can not see the calendar.

Here is the gem file;

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'fullcalendar-rails'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Here is the index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Events</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.description %></td>
        <td><%= event.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= event.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path %>

<br>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Here is the index.json.jbuilder file

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end
```

Here is the events.js.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
#
#
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(

  )
```

Here is the application js and css files;

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require fullcalendar
//= require_tree .

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require fullcalendar
 */
```

I do not know if that is relevant but when I scaffold Event rails created events.coffee folder but I changed it to events.js.coffee as in the example. 
All the js and css files are loaded when the index page loads but can not see any calendar on the page

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 with fullcalendar app init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912361/rails-4-with-fullcalendar-app-init)

Comment: But there is no answer?

Comment: check your browser console there might be issue of moment.js, if it is not loaded then you have to add it with this gem[https://github.com/derekprior/momentjs-rails]

Comment: follow this [link](https://github.com/derekprior/momentjs-rails) if you don't have moment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When load pages with [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), event ready of document will not be triggered.
Here is the document of [turlolinks events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events), it may help you.

Comment: But if I take out turbolinks gem and //= require turbolinks from application js file. It still does not show the calendar

Comment: First, make sure your function call will be triggered. Second, it looks like your fullCalendar call lack of parameters. Here is an example: http://fullcalendar.io/   the fullCalendar call of the example : http://fullcalendar.io/js/home.js?2.3.1